# CN1 - Dialog.dispose() is causing the parent form to go "back"

Tags: codenameone

I need some help understanding some strange behavior of a `Dialog.dispose()`.   I am trying to create a "loading" dialog that will be used when content is being downloaded before allowing the user to view it.  In this case, it's a sound file.

The problem I'm having is that when I `dispose()` the "loading" dialog, the current form receives a "Back" command on the simulator and transitions to the previous form on the navigation stack.

I pre-create the dialog at program start `initVars` with the following:

```
Dialog updatingDialog = new Dialog(updatingMessage);
updatingDialog.setLayout(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
updatingDialog.add(progressContainer);
updatingDialog.setDialogUIID("UpdateProgressDialog");
```

I navigate to the (GUI Builder) form with the problematic dialog using:

```
showForm(formName, null)
```

In that form, when a user clicks a button, I display the dialog, call `downloadUrlToStorage` (if the file isn't already cached in storage) and then call `dialog.dispose()`.  These are done using `Runnables` passed into a method in another class for reusability in different situations:

```
showLoading.run();
Display.getInstance().invokeAndBlock(()->{
    Util.downloadUrlToStorage(this.url, getStoredName(), false);
});
hideLoading.run();
```

`showLoading` and `hideLoading` are `Runnables` passed into the method from a calling method.  Here's how they are set (load is the loading dialog box):

```
showLoading = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
    if (!load.isVisible()){
            load.showModeless();
        }
    }
};

hideLoading = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        if (load.isVisible()){
            load.dispose();
        }
    }
};
```

So is there an obvious reason why `Dialog.dispose()` could cause the form the dialog is shown from to transition back, and how can I stop it??

Comment: thanks for the formatting cleanup, but the spelling is correct... that's how I spell "behaviour"  - Canadian eh! ;-)

Comment: Sorry about that, it was done by my autocorrect Grammarly Plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I believe I fixed my issue through a bit of trial and error, but I wanted to share how I resolved it in case others find something similar tripping them up.

I realized that using the same dialog over and over could be complicating things so I started creating a new dialog for each loading message instead and I seem to have corrected the behaviour (Yes I spelled that the Canadian way! ;-D ).

This leads me to the conclusion that a Dialog gets bound to a form and then when it's operated on again it can affect the original form.   The form that it navigated "back" to on dispose in my problem was the same form that the dialog was first shown on, leading me to think that was the cause.

Can anyone from CodenameOne confirm my diagnosis here that re-use of Dialogs on different forms could have unintended navigation consequences and is a best practice to avoid?

Comment: Yes, reusing `Dialog` instances has always been problematic as the parent is stored within the dialog so the dispose can "go" to the right place. Initially we thought this is something we can fix but there are some really tricky edge cases that prevented that. The good news is that creating a new instance is **really cheap**.

Comment: I've spent close to 72 hours sorting this as I was also using separate non-EDT threads for showing/removing dialogs under certain conditions and it nearly drove me mad. Fixed my issues by showing the right form before the dialog using `Display.getInstance().callSeriallyAndWait(()->form.show())`otherwise the dialog might still get the previous form if poped from a separate thread